# WPF DockPanel IsMouseOver only triggered when child controls are moused over

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a sort of tile system for my application. See the below code:

```
<WrapPanel Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1">
    <DockPanel Style="{StaticResource Panel}">
        <Label Content="Upload"/>
        <Image Width="40">
            <Image.Source>
                <BitmapImage DecodePixelWidth="40" UriSource="images/download.png" />
            </Image.Source>
        </Image>
    </DockPanel>
</WrapPanel>
```

As you can see, I have got the main container ([icode]WrapPanel[/icode]), and then I have got multiple [icode]DockPanel[/icode]'s which makeup the tile itself.

For some reason when I mouseover the DockPanel, the IsMouseOver trigger doesn't trigger, but it does when I mouse over any of it's children. Once triggered it remains triggered until my mouse leaves the DockPanel.

Here is the style:

```
<Style x:Key="Panel" TargetType="DockPanel">
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="4" />
    <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand" />
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="118" />
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="118" />
    <Setter Property="LastChildFill" Value="True" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF212121" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
    <Style.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Label">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Bottom" />
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="3" />
            <Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock" Value="Bottom" />
        </Style>
    </Style.Resources>
</Style>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Try to set DockPanel background to Transparent

Comment: Awesome thanks! Put that as an answer :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try to set DockPanel's background to Transparent.
When background is null, WPF will not include it in [hit test](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752097.aspx).